# Xcode Error When trying to set up today widget

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

When i created a new today wieget target, the app complains that there is no such framework called 'NotificationCenter.framework' Here are some images of the issue.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Check the path under the framework's `general` tab. Is it set to the actual path to the framework?

Comment: I think i accidentally deleted the entire NotificationCenter framework. How do i get it back?

Comment: Do i redownload xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Notification Center framework from github:

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS8-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework